# Clicking overview(recent) button on android device doesn't call onPause() and onStop() method. Why is that?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I remember that when I used the Android version 9 device before, when I clicked the Overview button, called the onPause and onStop method.

However, these method are not being called on Android 12th version of the device.

1. Is there any change in Android policy?
2. How can I call the onPause, onStop when I click the Overview button?

Comment: I tested with an app targeting API 33 on an Android 13 phone and it still calls onPause, and onStop when hitting the Recent app button. It's there anything special about your phone or any code changes recently?

Comment: Well i'm working for device manufacturer. So as far as I know, the company received API 32 code from Google and build it, so it may be different from the device you tested.

Comment: Then I cannot help further, because what you asked somehow breaks the normal behavior of the Activity lifecycle

Comment: I understand, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No
2. You cannot trigger the `onPause()` and `onStop()` methods yourself, these are triggered automatically by the system. According to figure 1 [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) `onPause()` is triggered in an activity when another activity moves to the foreground, and `onStop()` when the activity is no longer visible (applies to both Android 9 and 12). If you press the Recents button, both conditions are met and `onPause()` and `onStop()` are triggered in your activity.

So if you really don't observe `onPause()` and `onStop()` in all your apps, then you would have a serious problem with your IDE. Check whether `onPause()` is triggered  after all by adding the third line to the `onPause()` method and checking the log file to see whether you can find a line with the two specified strings:

```
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  Log.i("myAppName", "onPause is starting");
  ... // your code
}
```

Comment: I work in developing an privileged app for a device manufacturer, and I know that the Android OS is somewhat customized by company. 

I've already checked the log, but when the app enters the RecentViewList, it won't be captured.

Comment: I think this problem is my AOS itself. It says nothing has changed in the policy, so I think I need to check the launcher code.

Comment: Yes, as you said, the error must be somewhere else, not in the `onPause()` / `onStop()` methods. Good Luck!